# Existing linux installation, one disk, how to proceed with manual dual-boot Ubuntu installation?

Tags: dual-boot

I've got a new office PC and it has ALT Linux ver 9 installed.

I want to install Ubuntu, but Ubuntu's installer ver 18.04 (uefi) doesn't detect alt linux.

Here is what the disk(1 disk,gpt) looks like:

```
/dev/sda a
/dev/sda1 efi
/dev/sda2 swap (swap for alt linux)
/dev/sda3 ext4 (alt linux installed here)
/dev/sda4 ext4 (it looks like home for altlinux)
/dex/sda5 empty ext4 partition
```

How should I proceed with manually installing Ubuntu so that I could use dual-boot?

Tbh I'd rather completely delete altlinux, but we are not allowed to do it.

Thank you.

PS Thanx guys!  I successfully installed kubuntu in dual-boot mode. =)

Comment: You haven't given any release details, but my choice is always to use 'Something else' (or 'Manual Partitioning' if `calamares` installer, or kde_ui) and thus have exactly what I want.  I don't know *altlinux* (plus you gave no release details) so I'm not sure if sharing a $HOME is a good idea; it can have problems which may/may-not be your intention anyway.

Comment: That's quite easy. Choose "something else", select the existing `efi` as EFI, and select the `/dev/sda5` as `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Ubuntu Live USB, select "Install Ubuntu", then select "something else".

After that select `/dev/sda1` as `efi`, `/dev/sda5` as `/`.

You need to make sure that you boot from the Live USB in UEFI mode. That's probably the reason the installer doesn't see the existing system, becuase you booted in non-UEFI mode.

Comment: I did boot in uefi mode

Comment: OK, some info.

1) I;n trying to install kubuntu

2) The only thing i can do with existing efi partition is to change it into something else. so i guess I shouldn't touch it?

There is " device for bootloader information" and I can select there partition. Should I select there sda1?  

3) I set sda5 as /  and after I press continue it says sda2 will be formatted as swap.  Would this work OK , I mean this partition is used as swap for alt linux.

WIl "shared" swap partition work for two linux systems?

Cheers

Comment: You can use the existing efi partition. Nothing bad will happen with it. A couple of files will be added there. It should be selected as `efi`. Maybe they changed the explanation to :bootloader information", I am not sure. I suggest not using the swap partition. Ubuntu should create a swap file. But you can use the existing swap as well. It will work for both systems if you don't use hibernation.